# Prevent reverting a fragment transaction

Tags: android, fragment

I have added a fragment transaction to the back stack with `addToBackStack()`. Is it possible to forbid reverting the fragment transaction when the user presses the back button? I do not want `popBackStack()` because this actually reverts the transaction.

Comment: override back button click listener and create you own action for fragment

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() method where you are pressing back button and remove super.onBackPressed();

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //remove super.onBackPressed(); from here
    //And provide your functionality
}
```